# Disable ios native overscrolling and bouncing in ionic2 app

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, wkwebview, ionic-view

I am trying to really get rid of the native ios cordova overscrolling in my ionic2 app. By this, it should make the app looking more like a native app, not a browser embedded. But really, non of the params that I've tried work for me. I am using WKWEBVIEW at the moment, i tried another build without that plugin and to use the native UIWEBVIEW but same, the params does not work, and if I have a page with scrolling it just overscrolls.

I have tried all these, but no luck.

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```